# What does he say in video? What feelings?

Tags: single-word-requests, listening

Good afternoon!
What does he say at 2:50? What feelings? I don't understand.

[Motivation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26U_seo0a1g&t=170)

Comment: This is an american ascent. And unusual pronunciation. 
If I could find the answer, I would have already.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that he says "behind your *little* feelings".

Comment: Thanks. But why does he pronounce it so strange? Like "lou" ?

Comment: I believe it's actually a " 'lil ". Try to hear it that way.

Comment: Excuse me. But I disagree. I listened to it carefully on 0.75 and 0.25 speed 50 times. He also says it twice. There are no "lil". There is something like "lo" or "lou". But what is it? Other word or pronunciation of little?

Comment: @ГригорийХримян As a native speaker, I can say that it's definitely pronounced as "lil feelings" the first time and "little feelings" the second time.

Comment: Thank you. Understand now. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/li%27l